# Paypal API TransactionSearch Object Reference Not Set asp.net

Tags: asp.net, api, paypal

Ok Paypal drives me nuts.  I've taken their "sample code" directly from the latest area of xcom (or whatever they are calling it these days) and installed the DLL's just fine.  I'm doing a simple TransactionSearch as follows:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GenerateCodeSOAP.TransactionSearch t = new GenerateCodeSOAP.TransactionSearch();
        String mysearch = t.TransactionSearchnCode(Convert.ToDateTime(dtStart.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dtEnd.Text), "05S08011830926906");
        Response.Write("Results:<br/>" + mysearch);
        lblStatus.Text = "Finished";
    }
```

And here is the sample code I altered just slightly with my own API stuff in it:

```
public class TransactionSearch
{
    public TransactionSearch()
    {

    }

    public string TransactionSearchnCode(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate,string transactionId)
    {

        CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();
        IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();       

        // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
                    profile.APIUsername = "[removed for security]";
        profile.APIPassword = "[removed for security]";
        profile.APISignature = "[removed for security]";
        profile.Subject = "[removed for security]";
        profile.Environment = "live";

        // Create the request object.
        TransactionSearchRequestType concreteRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();          
        concreteRequest.Version="92.0";

        // Add request-specific fields to the request.
        concreteRequest.StartDate = startDate;
        concreteRequest.EndDate = endDate.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
        concreteRequest.EndDateSpecified = true;
        //concreteRequest.TransactionID=transactionId;

        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        TransactionSearchResponseType pp_response=new TransactionSearchResponseType();
        pp_response= (TransactionSearchResponseType) caller.Call("TransactionSearch", concreteRequest);
        return pp_response.Ack.ToString();

    }
}
```

No matter what I try (you'll see I commented out the transactionid just to give me back something) I get a Object Reference Not Set error on this line:

```
pp_response= (TransactionSearchResponseType) caller.Call("TransactionSearch", concreteRequest);
```

I know it's just "sample code" but this seems like this should be pretty straight forward.  I tried it via the sandbox and that clearly didn't work, so I have transactions in my own paypal account, so I setup the API credentials and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Haven't done Paypal in ages so this is more general - DEBUG and put a breakpoint in the line - you should get some error response from PayPal if the request was actually made (or an issue with the request preventing it from being made).

Comment: EdSF, you nailed it, but I'm unsure how I can mark yours as the answer.  I think you need to formally answer it.  The key here is the debug hint.  Paypal's sample code completely omitted the assignment of the APIProfile to the caller object.  Looking at the debug (which I should have right away....) it stood out like a sore thumb to me.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done Paypal in ages so this is more general - DEBUG and put a breakpoint in the line - you should get some error response from PayPal if the request was actually made (or an issue with the request preventing it from being made).